# I need help in json response in php

Tags: php, json, api

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($searching_user))
{
    $salon_name = ucfirst($row['service_name']);
    $salon_id = ucfirst($row['id']);
    $salon_address = ucwords($row['address']);
    $salon_area = ucwords($row['area']);
    $salon_city = ucwords($row['city']);
    $salon_specialty = ucwords($row['specialty']);
    $img = $row['image_url'];
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["service_name"] = $salon_name;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**after this I'm getting the response in this format**

> {"error":false,"service_name":"Mike
>   salon"}{"error":false,"service_name":"Michel salon"}
>       {"error":false,"service_name":"Michel salon"}{"error":false,"service_name":"Mike Salon"}
>       {"error":false,"service_name":"Etta Salon"}

**I simply want this response like this**

> [  {"error":false,"service_name":"Mike
>   salon"},{"error":false,"service_name":"Michel
>   salon"},{"error":false,"service_name":"Michel
>   salon"},{"error":false,"service_name":"Mike Salon"},
>   {"error":false,"service_name":"Etta Salon"}]

Kindly help me to get a proper response form for json .
Thanks

Comment: Can you please give a example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to encode single results, Try to create a array will all the results and encode it out side the loop.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searching_user)) {
    $salon_name = ucfirst($row['service_name']);
     $salon_id = ucfirst($row['id']);
     $salon_address = ucwords($row['address']);
     $salon_area = ucwords($row['area']);
     $salon_city = ucwords($row['city']);
     $salon_specialty = ucwords($row['specialty']);
     $img = $row['image_url'];
     $response["error"] = FALSE;
     $response["service_name"]=$salon_name;
     // Added this line
     $responses[] = $response;
}
//Encode all results
 echo json_encode($responses );
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't json_encode() the single results, but put them into an array and finally json_encode() that:

```
<?php
$response = [];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searching_user)) {
  $salon_name = ucfirst($row['service_name']); 
  $salon_id = ucfirst($row['id']);
  $salon_address = ucwords($row['address']);
  $salon_area = ucwords($row['area']);
  $salon_city = ucwords($row['city']);
  $salon_specialty = ucwords($row['specialty']);
  $img = $row['image_url'];

  $response[] = [
    'error' => FALSE,
    'service_name' => $salon_name,
    // you may want to add more attributes here...
  ];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I personally suggest to shorten this:

```
<?php
$response = [];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searching_user)) {
  $response[] = [
    'error'           => FALSE,
    'service_name'    => ucfirst($row['service_name']),
    'salon_id'        => $row['id'],
    'salon_address'   => ucwords($row['address']),
    'salon_area'      => ucwords($row['area']),
    'salon_city'      => ucwords($row['city']),
    'salon_specialty' => ucwords($row['specialty']),
    'img'             => $row['image_url'],
  ];
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) 
You save my night :P